# how to validate array of multiple arrays on ref variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a project in vue where i receive data (float values) and populate an input field to be edited.
Now the problem come if the field is empty hence the backend can't handle it since expecting a float value, not an empty string. The error of null value can come from user interaction/misstake and need to be aware of it.
I want to achieve a warning and prevent user to submit/save the data to backend.

I wonder if there is a way to handle this in the frontend??

in Setup() i declare the receiving array as ref

```
let labvalues = ref([]);
```

then in the axios call i fetch the data with selecting parameters and assign the labvalues like this

```
function successLoadLabvalue(data) {      
      labvalues.value = data.data;
```

Below is data printed to console on arrival, where lab_data is what I am putting in Input field

```
data arrived  
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
1
: 
date_time
: 
1680689190
journal_number
: 
770
lab_data
: 
(10) [31.329999923706055, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ore
: 
1
ptype
: 
1
res_data
: 
(10) [31.816999435424805, 0, 0.3377000093460083, 0.7167999744415283, 0.028200000524520874, 19.711999893188477, 0.02930000051856041, 0, 0.012299999594688416, 0]
sample_type
: 
"cell"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
2
: 
{date_time: 1680408502, journal_number: 730, lab_data: Array(10), ore: 1, ptype: 1, …}
3
: 
{date_time: 1680408301, journal_number: 729, lab_data: Array(10), ore: 1, ptype: 1, …}
4
: 
{date_time: 1680407670, journal_number: 728, lab_data: Array(10), ore: 1, ptype: 1, …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

And in the template area I draw the input depending on items arriving in a v-for loop

```
<tr v-for="item in labvalues" :key="item.journal_number">
```

and below assigning

```
<td v-if="editItem === true">
            <input
              id="9"
              v-model.number="item.lab_data[9]"
              title="Must contain a decimal number"
              pattern="([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})"
              type="text"
              @keypress="isNumber"              
              @focusin="chemValueChanged"                   
              class="form-control"
              required="true"
              autofocus
              
            />
      </td>
```

where the isNumber prevent char and replace ',' with a '.' including prevent doublettes of 'em

On submit, I put together the axios put call and attach labvalues.value as is

```
await axios({
        method: "put",
        url: BACKEND_PATH.value + "/lab_value",
        data: {
          lab-data: labvalues.value,
        },        
      });
```

Comment: You can use a validator or else. In the end you need to either process data to make it suitable for a request, or not send it.

Comment: any suggestion on validator?

Comment: Totally depends on your case. E.g. Vuelidate